# Has every finite group a minimal presentation?

Tags: finite-groups, conjectures, group-presentation

For a finite group $G$ let $d(G)$ be the minimal number of generators of $G$ and let $r(G)$ be the minimal number such that $G$ has a finite presentation with $r(G)$ relators. Call a presentation with $d(G)$ generators and $r(G)$ relators a *minimal presentation*.

> **Question:** Has every finite group a minimal presentation?

Comment: This is an open question.

Comment: I presume your question is means to read "**Question:** Has every finite group a minimal presentation ?" not representation. But I don't want to edit it, just in case...