# What is the definition of a minimal presentation of a group?

Tags: definition, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm working on a problem on the braid monodromy of complex lines arrangements in $\mathbb{C}^{2}.$ I have the following question. It's just a simple definition. However, I didn't find anywhere.

> Let $G$ be a group and let $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ be a presentation of $G.$ What does it mean that such presentation is *minimal*?

Thank you very much for everyone will answer and kind regards.

Comment: In most cases, if the group is finite-generated then minimality if referd to the cardinality of $|S|$. That is a presentation is minimal if $S$ is a minimal set of generators.

Comment: And what about the number of relators?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217774/104041):

> For a finite group $G$ let $d(G)$ be the minimal number of generators of $G$ and let $r(G)$ be the minimal number such that $G$ has a finite presentation with $r(G)$ relators. Call a presentation with $d(G)$ generators and $r(G)$ relators a *minimal presentation*.

So, using your notation, both $|S|$ and $|R|$ are the smallest they can be for $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ to be a presentation of $G$.